# Mutex needed in MSMQ?

Tags: multithreading, msmq, mutex, visual-c++-6

I'm browsing source codes from two applications sharing one queue using MSMQ. The first application has a thread that writes into the queue while the second application has another thread that reads from the queue. Ordinarily, if you're implementing your own queue, the applications would need a mutex when accessing the queue, right? However, I could not find any mutex/critical section in the source codes of these applications. Did I just miss something? Or does MSMQ not need any mutex since it is handled internally, is there such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx) documentation states that:

> Only the following methods are thread
>   safe: BeginPeek, BeginReceive,
>   EndPeek(IAsyncResult),
>   EndReceive(IAsyncResult),
>   GetAllMessages, Peek, and Receive.

MSMQ.Send() is ***not*** inherently thread-safe.

> Send is thread safe, as long as you
>   always send a Message object and never
>   use send a .NET object directly. Using
>   the Message object, BTW, is always a
>   good idea - since it lets you add
>   label, timeouts, recoverable option
>   and all this stuff that make your MSMQ
>   solution a real enterprise solution.
>
> ```
> class Program
> {
>     static MessageQueue outQueue;
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         outQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\mtQueue"); 
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
>         {
>             Thread thr = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
>
>             thr.Start();
>         }
>     } 
>
>     static void MyThreadProc()
>     {
>         Message msg = new Message();
>         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
>         {
>             msg.Label = string.Format("{0} : {1}",
>                                      Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
>                                       i);
>             outQueue.Send(msg);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

From: [Is Send() thread safe?](http://msmq.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!393534E869CE55B7!293.entry)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your last statement. Create a separate instance of the queue on each thread and let MSMQ handle messages from different threads - do I need to use mutex for this?

Comment: Yes, if I create a separate instance of the MSMQ object on each thread, then I don't need to use a mutex right?

Comment: How come I dont' see your answer "Create a separate instance of the queue on each thread and let MSMQ handle messages from different threads" anymore.. This was actually the one that made it correct.